# HABTM join table validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

How can uniqueness validated on a HABTM association?

A User can be on many Teams and Many Teams can have a User. But how do you stop a user added to the same team twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the DB, you do this by putting a unique constraint on the {user, team} tuple in your join table

Comment: what would the migration for that be?

Comment: `add_index :team_members, [:team_id, :user_id], unique: true` I think

Comment: do you know where I can find out more on adding DB level validations?

Comment: I also had to add a rescue when the DB raised and exception

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this validation

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :team_id
```

Comment: does that go in the User model or the Team?

Comment: In the middle. See how has many throug works. YouTube should have a a TeamMembership model in the middle like a bridge table

Comment: I'm using a HABTM relationship, is it still possible to create the validation or will i need to convert it to a has_many through?

Comment: I don't have any experience in those. I always used has-many throught to achieve many to many relation.